# Aggregating columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame of n columns and r rows. I want to determine which column is correlated most with column 1, and then aggregate these two columns. The aggregated column will be considered the new column 1. Then, I remove the column that is correlated most from the set. Thus, the size of the date is decreased by one column. I then repeat the process, until the data frame `result` has has n columns, with the second column being the aggregation of two columns, the third column being the aggregation of three columns, etc. I am therefore wondering if there is an efficient or quicker way to get to the result I'm going for. I've tried various things, but without success so far. Any suggestions?

```
n <- 5
r <- 6


> df
    X1   X2   X3   X4   X5
1 0.32 0.88 0.12 0.91 0.18
2 0.52 0.61 0.44 0.19 0.65
3 0.84 0.71 0.50 0.67 0.36
4 0.12 0.30 0.72 0.40 0.05
5 0.40 0.62 0.48 0.39 0.95
6 0.55 0.28 0.33 0.81 0.60
```

This is what `result` should look like:

```
> result
    X1   X2   X3   X4   X5
1 0.32 0.50 1.38 2.29 2.41
2 0.52 1.17 1.78 1.97 2.41
3 0.84 1.20 1.91 2.58 3.08
4 0.12 0.17 0.47 0.87 1.59
5 0.40 1.35 1.97 2.36 2.84
6 0.55 1.15 1.43 2.24 2.57
```

Comment: Have you profiled your code? I guess that carrying out `cor(temp)` twice takes some time for larger data. Assign it to an object and make these computations only once. Moreover, `cor(temp)` computes all correlations, but you only want the correlation with the first column. Try something like `sapply(temp[,-1], function(x) cor(temp[,1], x)` to get the correlations with only the first column.

Comment: @coffeinjunky What does it mean to 'profile code'? Also, how would I incorporate your suggestion into this script? I've tried adding it in the loop, but I'm not sure exactly how to.

Comment: For profiling, see e.g. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html

Comment: @coffeinjunky I have profiled the code, and found that indeed that the bottleneck takes place at continuously calculating the correlations.

Comment: In that case, try `which.max(sapply(temp[,-1], function(x) cor(temp[,1], x) ))` instead. It will go through each column of `temp` and computes the correlation with the first column. Now you are computing all possible correlations (twice), even those that you don't care about.

Comment: I've incorporated this in the loop like this: 'for (i in 2:n) { mch <- which.max(sapply(temp[,-1], function(x) cor(temp[,1], x) ))  result[,i] <- temp[,1] + temp[,mch] temp[,1] <- result[,i] temp[,mch] <- NULL rm(mch) }'

Which gives `Error in cor(temp[, 1], x) : incompatible dimensions`. It seems to be going wrong as I delete columns from temp, but I can't figure out how to solve this. Any ideas? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
for (i in 2:n) {
  maxcor <- names(which.max(sapply(temp[,-1, drop=F], function(x) cor(temp[, 1], x) )))
  result[,i] <- temp[,1] + temp[,maxcor] 
  temp[,1] <- result[,i] # Set result as new 1st column
  temp[,maxcor] <- NULL # Remove column
}
```

The error was caused because in the last iteration, subsetting `temp` yields a single vector, and standard R behavior is to reduce the class from dataframe to vector in such cases, which causes `sapply` to pass on only the first element, etc.

One more comment: currently, you are using the most positive correlation, not the strongest correlation, which may also be negative. Make sure this is what you want.

---

To adress your question in the comment: Note that your old code could be improved by avoiding repeat computation. For instance,

```
   mch <- match(c(max(cor(temp)[-1,1])),cor(temp)[,1])
```

contains the command `cor(temp)` twice. This means each and every correlation is computed twice. Replacing it with

```
  cortemp <- cor(temp)
  mch <- match(c(max(cortemp[-1,1])),cortemp[,1])
```

should cut the computational burden of the initial code line in half.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. This works perfectly. One more thing: you said 'Assign it to an object and make these computations only once.' What do you mean by that? Isn't it already assigned to an object (temp)? If not, how could I do this to make it run faster?

Comment: Regarding the correlations: All values will be above 0, so that shouldn't be a problem then, right?

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean. Thank you for the clarification. In your solution you already addressed that issue, correct?

Comment: Yes, my solution avoids both computing them twice, and it avoids computation of correlations with among columns you are not interested in.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time. Your solution has helped me a lot and has made the processing much quicker.

Answer (score 2):

I think most of the slowness and eventual crash comes from memory overheads during the loop and not from the correlations (though that could be improved too as @coffeeinjunky says). This is most likely as a result of the way data.frames are modified in R. Consider switching to data.tables and take advantage of their "assignment by reference" paradigm. For example, below is your code translated into data.table syntax. You can time the two loops, compare perfomance and comment the results. cheers.

```
n <- 5L
r <- 6L

result <- setDT(data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=r,ncol=n)))
temp <- copy(df) # Create a temporary data frame in which I calculate the correlations
set(result, j=1L, value=temp[[1]]) # The first column is the same

for (icol in as.integer(2:n)) {
  mch <- match(c(max(cor(temp)[-1,1])),cor(temp)[,1]) # Determine which are correlated most
  set(x=result, i=NULL, j=as.integer(icol), value=(temp[[1]] + temp[[mch]]))# Aggregate and place result in results datatable
  set(x=temp, i=NULL, j=1L, value=result[[icol]])# Set result as new 1st column
  set(x=temp, i=NULL, j=as.integer(mch), value=NULL) # Remove column
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm not quite sure how to use data tables. When I try your suggestion, I get the following error: `Error in set(x = result, i = NULL, j = as.integer(icol), value = (temp[[1]] +  : RHS of assignment to existing column 'X2' is zero length but not NULL. If you intend to delete the column use NULL. Otherwise, the RHS must have length > 0; e.g., NA_integer_. If you are trying to change the column type to be an empty list column then, as with all column type changes, provide a full length RHS vector such as vector('list',nrow(DT)); i.e., 'plonk' in the new column.`

Comment: @Joseph Yeah, I missed translating `<-` to `copy()` which is how temp should be created from df in data.table. If you are working with large amounts of data and have memory/speed issues, data.table is inevitable..[see this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will take a look at that. Thank you for your solution, it works perfectly.